# What is the goal and the rationale of a governing body for psychologists to require its members to adopt certain posture in social media?

Tags: ethics

The news that precipitated this question is [Jordan Peterson loses fight with psychology college over mandatory social media training](https://nationalpost.com/news/canada/exclusive-jordan-peterson-loses-fight-with-psychology-college-over-mandatory-social-media-training).

My question is *not* about free speech and is *not* about which party is right in this case.  I also affirm a board's right to introduce limiting conditions for its members for the good of the profession, which is *not* the question here.

I'm interested in how a regulatory board of psychologists define

- the **goal** of establishing these social media policies (which may or may not coincide with a more general "personal PR" policy encompassing interviews with TV / magazine, for example),
- the **character** of the policies (i.e. *how* the policies are worded), and
- the **parameters** of the policies when balancing free expression vs. representing the profession in the public.

Comment: If the question is not on topic where, I appreciate a suggestion where I should post this question.  I also cannot find a proper tag for it, which I would think should be something like "practicioners", "governing-body", etc.

Comment: I won't mod-hammer the question, but I don't really think it's on-topic. Unfortunately there is no other SE site I can think of that would be. I don't think this is something you can reason from general principles except that regulatory boards are *people*, and *people* have motivations. Those motivations are unique to each person and situation. Usually you can guess at someone's motivation but only know it if they tell you what it is; even then, you can be skeptical that their answer is accurate.

Comment: I would *guess* that a motivation here is that psychologists tend to think helping people with their mental health is a good thing, so a psychologist who says things that are harmful to mental health is like a doctor walking around assaulting people.